# axios is showing data in console but not posting in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, react-native, post, axios, expo

Hi I am using axios to post my string and some buffer data in my mongodb server.Data is working fine with post but when I try to post data using axios it does show on console but it doesnot post data in mongo db here is my axios post code

axios.js

```
const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("name", this.state.name);
      formData.append("title", this.state.title);
      formData.append("contact", this.state.contact);
      formData.append("price", this.state.price);
      formData.append("description", this.state.description);
      formData.append("selectedcat", this.state.selectedcat);
      formData.append("selectedcity", this.state.selectedcity);

      formData.append("imgforsell", this.state.imgforsell);

axios
  .post(
   // `http://${
     // Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.88.45" : "localhost"
    //}:4000/pets/addpets`,
  
    'http://http://192.168.88.45:4000/pets/addpets',
    formData,
    {headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }}

    
  )
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
    // res.status(500).json(err)  don't do this, it's not Express
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",
    });
  });
```

and here is the console data

Object {
"code": undefined,
"columnNumber": undefined,
"config": Object {
"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
"data": "{"_parts":[["name","Saad"],["title","Pets"],["contact","12345678900"],["price","123"],["description","Post"],["selectedcat","Pets Accessories"],["selectedcity","Karachi"],["imgforsell",{"cancelled":false,"width":2160,"exif":{"DateTime":"2015:11:04 17:32:48","Software":"Adobe Photoshop CC (Windows)","XResolution":72,"ImageWidth":2160,"Orientation":0,"ImageLength":1620,"ResolutionUnit":2,"LightSource":0,"ColorSpace":1,"JPEGInterchangeFormat":302,"YResolution":72,"Compression":6,"JPEGInterchangeFormatLength":5674},"height":1620,"base64":"/9j/4QG+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAESAAQAAAABAAAAAAEAAAQAAAABAAAIcAEaAAUAAAABAAAAngExAAIAAAAdAAAApgICF/nat node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediatesat node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guardat node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue

update.js

```
 const petsObject = {
          name: this.state.name,
          title: this.state.title,
          contact: this.state.contact,
          price: this.state.price,
          description: this.state.description,
          selectedcat:this.state.selectedcat,
          imgforsell:this.state.imgforsell
          
        };
        

    axios
  .post(
   // `http://${
    //  Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.88.45" : "localhost"
   // }:4000/pets/addpets`,
  
    //'http://192.168.88.45:4000/pets/addpets/',
    'http://localhost:4000/Pets/addpets/',
   // formData,
petsObject,
   
   
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      transformRequest: (formData,headers) => {
       return formData; // this is doing the trick
      },
    },
  
    
  )
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
   
   // .then(res => {
     // console.log('Data Posted',res);
      
   // }


  }
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
    
    // res.status(500).json(err)  don't do this, it's not Express
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({
      name: "",
      title: "",
      contact: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      selectedcat: "",
      selectedcity: "",
      imgforsell: "",
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted this part:

{
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

and got response from server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).